# Makefile with different source folder for test target

Tags: c++, makefile

I am very new to C++ makefiles and I have the makefile below which I mostly copied from somewhere on the internet. My contribution to the makefile is the "test" target, which is the problem.

My code is organized in **include** (for headers), **src** (for sources) and **test** (for test sources) directories. For the standard target I want to build all files in the src folder which also includes the main.cpp file. To make the test build I want to build all files in the **src** folder *except* main.cpp and additionally all files in the **test** folder. I hoped that my test target would achieve that, but it fails. It just build the files from the standard target.

How can I correct my mistakes.

Thank you

The makefile I use:

```
APP=myappname

SRC_DIR=src
INC_DIR=include
OBJ_DIR=obj
BIN_DIR=bin
TEST_SRC_DIR=test
MAIN_CPP_NAME=main.cpp

CC=g++
LD=g++
CFLAGS=-O2 -c -Wall -std=c++17
LFLGAS=
DFLAGS=-g3 -O0 -DDEBUG
INCFLAGS=-I$(INC_DIR)

SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
HEADERS=$(wildcard $(INC_DIR)/*.hpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
DEPENDS=$(OBJ_DIR)/.depends


.PHONY: all
all: $(BIN_DIR)/$(APP)

.PHONY: debug
debug: CFLAGS+=$(DFLAGS)
debug: all

.PHONY: test
test:   SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
test: SOURCES=$(filter-out $(SRC_DIR)/$(MAIN_CPP_NAME), $(SOURCES))
test: OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
test: TEST_SOURCES=$(wildcard $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
test: OBJECTS+=$(TEST_SOURCES:$(TEST_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
test: all

$(BIN_DIR)/$(APP): $(OBJECTS) | $(BIN_DIR)
$(LD) $(LFLGAS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: | $(OBJ_DIR)
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(DEPENDS): $(SOURCES) | $(OBJ_DIR)
$(CC) $(INCFLAGS) -MM $(SOURCES) | sed -e 's!^!$(OBJ_DIR)/!' >$@

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(DEPENDS)
endif


$(BIN_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@
$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to write a sophisticated makefile without understanding the basics, which is almost impossible. Let's try a very simple approach.

First, suppose the source files are

```
src/main.cpp
src/func.cpp
test/unit.cpp
test/global.cpp
```

Now we need a list of the object files that `test` will need.

```
SOURCES:=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp) # this will be src/main.cpp src/func.cpp
NON_MAIN_SOURCES:=$(filter-out $(SRC_DIR)/$(MAIN_CPP_NAME), $(SOURCES)) # this will be src/func.cpp
TEST_DIR_SOURCES:=$(wildcard $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp) # this will be test/unit.cpp test/global.cpp
TEST_SOURCES:=$(notdir $(NON_MAIN_SOURCES) $(TEST_DIR_SOURCES)) # this will be func.cpp unit.cpp global.cpp
TEST_OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(TEST_SOURCES)) # this will be obj/func.o obj/unit.o obj/global.o
```

(Note that you must avoid name collisions between `src/` and `test/`, e.g. having a `src/func.cpp` and also a `test/func.cpp`. This is a consequence of your directory structure; there's no way for the makefile to work around it.)

Now we must tell Make how to build those object files. We can start with a rule for the sources in `src`:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

(I have omitted the `$(OBJ_DIR)` prerequisite for simplicity. For now, you will be responsible for making sure that `obj/` exists.)

Now for the sources in `test`. A crude but effective approach is to add a rule for them:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(TEST_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

There are more sophisticated ways, but you must master the basics first.

Finally, the rule to build `bin/mytestname`:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/mytestname: $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

That's enough for now.